# Ranking Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my Query. I want to select data from my Ranking Query.
My query output is Perfect Like:

```
------------------------------
 Rank | ID | Username | Value
-------------------------------
  1   | 5 | Julian    | 5000
  2   | 2 | Masha     | 2400
  3   | 4 | Misha     | 2300
  4   | 1 | Jackson   | 1900
  5   | 9 | Beruang   | 400
-------------------------------
```

But when I select ID = 4, the output like this:

```
------------------------------
 Rank | ID | Username | Value
-------------------------------
  ***1***   | 4 | Misha     | 2300
-------------------------------
```

The output of ranking is 1, not 3.

My Query is :

```
 SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
       a.id, a.username
FROM  partimer a CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
# WHERE  a.id = 4
ORDER By id;
```

Comment: How would you expect it to be different from `1` is you compute it on the fly and select only one row?

Comment: Yes i expect like the multiple rows, i expect 3. Yes sir i just select only one row for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Rank` is dinamically computed, you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
       , a.id
       , a.username
  FROM partimer a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
  ORDER BY value
) p
WHERE p.id = 4;
```

This way, you store temporary table with rank, and then select from it.

Answer (score 0):

you should like this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     ...{your Query}...
) qry
WHERE  qry.id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rank is calculated dynamically in the query. The issue here is that these dynamic calculations are applied **after** the where clause. In other words, when MySQL executes your query, it first filters out all the rows that adhere to the `where` clause, and only then applies the rank calculation. In the given query, the row with `id=4` is indeed the 1st row between all the rows that adhere to the where clause.

One way to get your desired behavior is to perform the original query first and only then filter the results by using this query as a subquery and applying the `where` clause to the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT     @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, a.id, a.username
        FROM       partimer a 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
        ORDER By id) t
WHERE  id = 4
```